# Stratum Server Exception "[coin] is not connected"

Tags: mining-pools, client, python, stratum

When i running 'twistd -ny launcher.tac' i getting the following Exception. The connection okay. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
2017-01-30 19:33:43,094 INFO bitcoin_rpc # Checking for submitblock
2017-01-30 19:33:43,097 DEBUG bitcoin_rpc # submitblock detected.
017-01-30 19:33:43,097 INFO mining # Found submitblock
2017-01-30 19:33:43,101 ERROR mining # Coind Error: Guncoin is not connected!
```

Thanks,
Your help will appreciated!

Comment: What are you doing? What is `twistd`? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @Murch Based on filenames, I think it's [this fork of stratum](https://github.com/Crypto-Expert/stratum-mining)

Comment: Thanks for your reply....

         Actually i am not familiar with Python,                                                 
         I am just followed this instructions ,                                                     
          https://github.com/Crypto-Expert/stratum-mining/wiki/Getting-Started-With-Stratum, 
         But, it is showing above exception

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this problem then check your coin daemon settings.

I got it because my client didn't find any nodes to connect to. I found a list of nodes and added them in my COIN CLIENT SETTINGS.

I.e:

```
addnode=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Restart the client, run client-cli getinfo to make sure you're downloading blocks. If it works you should be seeing

```
ERROR mining __init__.setup # CoinD downloading blockchain... will check back in 30 sec
```

Let your client update to the latest block and everything should be just peachy.